# document.onkeydown doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard-events, keydown

I'm in trouble, I got this site (bummer.wtf) where every time you hit a button this button brings you in a different page. Everything works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but in firefox I get trouble, nothing seems to happen.

```
    document.onkeydown = function(event){
var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
     if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 65) 
     {
        window.location.href = "about.html"
     }
     if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 67) 
     {
        window.location.href = "contact.html"
     }
    }
```

What can I do? I got a similar script for the enter button, but that one work perfectly even on firefox.

Comment: Have you traced it? The first question is if the code is not being called or if it is being called but not working.

Comment: `window.event` is not standard, add `event` as parameter of your function

Comment: yeah, i did it but notingh happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox uses `event.key` not `event.code` check that instead (actually check both for it to work everywhere). Also you should add `event` as a parameter. If on IE `window.event` will exist; however for others it will not.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    var keyCode = event.key|| event.code;
    if (keyCode == 65) {
        window.location.href = "about.html"
    }

    if(keyCode == 67) {
        window.location.href = "contact.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to use `event.which` and add event as parameter, but  nothing changed

Comment: You want your first two lines to be something more along the lines of `document.onkeydown = function(e) { var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode; ...` to check both.

Comment: You weren't actually using the variable set after using it, I updated the answer with it.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!! everything works now! I really appriciate your help.